# How to add empty plot to multiplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say you want to create a figure like the one below.

[image]

I want to use the [multiplot](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/) function, based on `ggplot2`. How can I add empty plots to get the triangular output with multiplot?

MWE below:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Multiplot function from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/
multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
  library(grid)

  # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
  plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

  numPlots = length(plots)

  # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
  if (is.null(layout)) {
    # Make the panel
    # ncol: Number of columns of plots
    # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
    layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                    ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
  }

 if (numPlots==1) {
    print(plots[[1]])

  } else {
    # Set up the page
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))

    # Make each plot, in the correct location
    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
      # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
      matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))

      print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                      layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
    }
  }
}

# Example plot
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()

multiplot(p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p,cols=3)
```

This produces

[image]

Comment: You just posted a comment to my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424650/how-to-jump-to-a-slide-in-a-beamer-presentation/438955?noredirect=1#comment1326459_438955 I left tex.se a while ago, so I won't reply you there. Did you compile 2 times? The `\begin{frame}[label=....]` is usually more powerful for beamer because these label can also be used for things like `\againframe`, no worries about overlays etc Can you make a MWE of what you tried and did not work?

Comment: @samcarter How odd. It works in your MWE but not in my current (quite long) presentation. It's probably pointless to debug my slides (and to be honest, don't have the time right now). If no one else has complained, then it's my problem. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `""` to multiplot, to create an empty element:

```
multiplot(p,"","",p,p,"",p,p,p,cols=3)
```

Alternative, create an empty plot and add it to the list:

```
p1 <- ggplot() + theme_void()
multiplot(p,p1,p1,p,p,p1,p,p,p,cols=3)
```

Either way, you get

[image]

Answer (score 4):

alternatively, grid.arrange() can use a layout,

```
m = matrix(NA, 3, 3)
m[upper.tri(m, TRUE)] = 1:6
lp = replicate(6, ggplot(), FALSE)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = lp, layout_matrix = m)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the `multiplot` function was put together, several packages have come out that take care of tasks like this and have more functionality, including [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/), [`egg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/), and [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork). I think `patchwork` is best suited to this task because of the way it builds grids, and because of its `plot_spacer` function that creates empty `ggplot` objects for filler.

`patchwork` has a set of arithmetic for putting plots together, but `+` is the simplest one. Your code that you already have would become this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
s <- plot_spacer()

p + p + p +
s + p + p +
s + s + p +
  plot_layout(ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

However, the example you posted at first is more complex, since it's got multiple variables shown against each other. You could build this in `patchwork`, ideally with some tidyeval to simplify multiple `ggplot` calls, or you could use a scatterplot matrix function, such as the one in `GGally`.

I made a more complex dataset, closer to what would have been used in your top example.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(GGally)

df <- tibble(
  id = rep(1:100, times = 4),
  key = rep(letters[1:4], each = 100),
  value = map(1:4, ~rnorm(100, mean = .)) %>% reduce(c)
) %>%
  spread(key, value)

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      id     a     b     c     d
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 1.89  0.912  2.96  4.92
#> 2     2 2.58  1.12   3.38  3.85
#> 3     3 0.730 2.92   2.64  5.16
#> 4     4 2.04  4.30   2.63  5.85
#> 5     5 1.28  1.41   3.82  3.35
#> 6     6 1.77  1.60   2.79  5.54
```

For the diagonal labels, I built a custom geom using `GGally`'s helper functions and a bit of tidyeval (`quo_name`). This will give you a label on the diagonal of the matrix, instead of the default density plot.

```r
diag_label <- function(data, mapping) {
  var_name <- quo_name(mapping[[1]])
  ggplot(data, mapping) +
    ggally_text(var_name, color = "black")
}

ggpairs(df, columns = 2:ncol(df),
        upper = list(continuous = "points"),
        lower = list(continuous = "blank"),
        diag = list(continuous = diag_label),
        progress = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

There's plenty more you can tweak to get the axes and labels to look like that first example.